# UITableView visibleCells is returning wrong cells after contentOffset

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableView. I use a CADisplayLink to call some code that scrolls the tableView. I do this because I want to customize the time that it takes to scroll instead of using UITableView methods.

I want some easing so I call `invalidate` on the displayLink scrolling and then do another contentOffset to make it look nice. I scroll up 25 points. I then call `NSArray *array = self.tableView.visibleCells` but I get the cells from before I do the final scroll after I invalidate. For example, my array holds numbers 1-8 and I start at the bottom so 6,7,8 are present in the tableView upon start. I press a UIButton and it scrolls for 2.1 seconds. It stops, calls another method and scrolls back the other way for 25 points. My tableView shows

> 3 4 5

but my NSLog statements show

> 2 3 4

The issue is that I can't get the proper index or cell after the scroll.

```
-(void)scrollRoller{

    self.displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(automaticScroll:)];

    [self.displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

}

-(void)automaticScroll:(CADisplayLink*)displayLink
{
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(self.tableView.contentOffset.x, self.tableView.contentOffset.y - 5) animated:NO];

    double test = self.displayLink.duration *self.displayLink.frameInterval;

    self.counter = self.counter + test;

    if (self.counter >= 2.1){

        [self.displayLink invalidate];


        [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(self.tableView.contentOffset.x, self.tableView.contentOffset.y + 25) animated:YES];

        NSArray* cells = self.tableView.visibleCells;

        NSLog(@"cells in first method %@", cells);
      self.counter = 0.0;

    }
```

Comment: Customize the time to scroll? Have you tried wrapping `[tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(x,y)];` inside a `[UIView animateWithDuration:];` block ?

Comment: @Zhang yes, I have but the cell refuse makes it so it scrolls to a cell but the intermediate cells don't display. For instance, cells 98-100 will display and so will cells 1-3, but cells 4-97 won't as the scroll with UIAnimation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some testing with a similar issue on `UICollectionView`, I think I figured out what's going on.

`visibleCells` gets updated after the corresponding `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method is called. When you directly apply a `contentOffset` to the `UIScrollView` (or its subclasses), probably a call to `setNeedsDisplay` is made to trigger an update of the `UITableView` or `UICollectionView` in the next screen update.

So `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` isn't guaranteed to be called immediately. As a result, your call to `visibleCells` is executed before the screen update, and doesn't return the cells you'd expect.

To solve your issue, you should call `indexPathForRowAtPoint:` or `indexPathsForRowsInRect:`.

Comment: Yes, I came to a similar conclusion a while ago and used `indexPathsForRowAtPoint:` and assigning a point in the superview's coordinated system. I used that method to grab the indexPaths.

Answer (score 2):

For a collection view you can use

```
var visibleIndexes : [IndexPath] {
    let collectionViewBounds = self.bounds // the collection view visible container
    let paths =  gamesCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.layoutAttributesForElements(in:collectionViewBounds)!.map { $0.indexPath }.sorted(by: <)
    return paths
}
```